# Create a simple function in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create and test a function named f_add20 that accepts one integer parameter. The function then adds 20 and returns the result as an integer.

Here is the code I have created thus far..I have been troubleshooting it for an hour. I know this is simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 delimiter $
 create function f_add20 (num int)
returns int
 begin
 declare final int;
select num into final + 20
from dual;
return final;
 end $
 delimiter;

 /*Use function created above*/
 select f_add20(3) from dual;
```

Comment: No need for the `select`, just use `return num + 20;`

Answer (score 0):

Change `select num into final + 20` to `select num + 20 into final`.